# How to make Phaser.Geom.Line draggalble?

Tags: phaser-framework

1). I want to know how to make a line, created with Phaser.Geom.Line, draggable?
or
2). how to draw a line with Phaser.Gameobjects.Line(); ??

I am able to create line with (1) but can not make it draggable. But on the other hand I can not create a line with (2) although there are no errors in console.
Please help. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Mirza Habib Khan. Consider providing some code so people can know how to help you. For more information, take a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Ok, when I use this "line01 = new Phaser.Geom.Line(200, 400, 400, 400);" It draws a line. but when I set it interactive to make it draggable with "line01 = new Phaser.Geom.Line(200, 400, 400, 400).setInteractive(); error says its not a function. When I use " line02 = new Phaser.GameObjects.Line(this,20 ,22 ,50,150,180,50, 0xff0000, 155).setInteractive(); " it gives no error but also doen't draw the line. I want a draggable line in PhaserJS.

Comment: Gameobjects can be dragged in phaserjs, phaser.geom.line is not a game object but phaser.gameobjects.line is a game object.